# How to use / create wcf rest methods

Tags: c#, wcf

i still make my FIRST WCF REST service and i have a simple question. I hope so my service will be use from php, python, java and asp.net

How better is to do :

- set / return objects as method parameters or maybe better is work in arrays ?
- all parameters take as string, or normaly typed (int, string, float etc.)

I think for ASP.NET better is use objects, but in jquery / php arrays ?

If i use arrays (probably string) i will have a lot of conversion and i must remember what index return how value, in object model i will have a lot of DTO objects.

How to do it optymality. Maybe build methods with a lot of string variables, validate it, packed to poco class (sometimes / often) some parameters in this class will be null, send it to repository class and add it to database. In return way take what you want from database (poco class with null, becouse you not always take select all fields), and returns result to array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use some standard such as Atom for packaging your outputs (and accepting non-GET inputs). Most languages have Atom readers/writers so  developers in pretty much any language will have an easier time inter-operating with your REST service. On the WCF side you can use the .NET Atom/RSS libraries, so it is easier for you too. This would also allow you to take inputs as Atom feeds through POST/PUT.

This not something new, and there is plenty of [precedent](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/05/robinson-rest-enterprise) on doing this. I've done it and feel it has some advantages.